# Bootstrap pull-right stack DIV together when view in mobile device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider the code

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
  <div id="right" class="span4 pull-right"> right </div>
  <div class="span8"> left </div>
</div>

</div>
```

And CSS

```
#left {
    background-color:red;
}
```

When view in a mobile device or with narrow screen, the left DIV is under right DIV (which is fine) but the background color is start from the right DIV, see the attachment
[image]

So how to make the red background only appear on the bottom?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6F4dg/

Comment: Do you want this left and right id to appear in same row?

Answer (score 1):

```
#left {
    background-color:red;
}

#right {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
```

Disable float and clear both, `#right` will be on top and `#left` at the bottom with red background.

Answer (score 0):

You cant separate the divs and try out.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div id="right" class="span4">right</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left">
            <div id="left" class="span8">left</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle:[Updated Code](http://jsfiddle.net/LcfSP/)

Answer (score -2):

You are using Bootstrap 2 classes, I suggest you upgrade your project to Bootstrap 3. It has grid classes for various display-sizes and allows you to specify how columns should behave depending on the display-size.

So you could do something like this ([Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6dvcH/)):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="right" class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4">right</div>
    <div id="left" class="col-xs-8 col-lg-8">left </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `col-lg-8` and `col-lg-4` are for **desktop** and
`col-xs-8` and `col-xs-4` are for **small devi
ces**

See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid for more information.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 has the same problem with pulling right and left.